# react-bootstrap using webpack

Tags: webpack, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use react-bootstrap with web pack. I am able to get a bootstrap `<Button>` on a page, but there is no styles attached?
I have installed:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.1.11",
    "babel-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.12.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router": "^0.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.4",
    "react": "^0.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.22.6",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Loaders in webpack.config.js

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'], include: path.join(__dirname, 'app') },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      { test: /\.png$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

react-bootstrap does not include the bootstrap styles.

As they put it on their [Getting Started](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) page:

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included CSS. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

You should import the styles from `bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css`. Since you already have a loader setup for css files and have a dependency on bootstrap, it's as simple as

```
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

or

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: You can also use the webpack less-loader and pick and choose which bootstrap components you want to include. This will allow you to have webpack give you a much smaller minified bundle when you are done.

Comment: This worked fairly well, but for me it we ```require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');```

Comment: Probably you will also have to configure loaders for fonts [that way](https://github.com/gowravshekar/bootstrap-webpack#usage). I additionally had to copy the line for woff and change it to woff2 to support both of those types.

Comment: @AnilGupta No. You should require `react-bootstrap` directly.

Comment: What am I missing? Aren't you folks getting errors about eot, woff2, ttf, and svg files? I had to use [this advice](http://blog.theodybrothers.com/2015/07/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-only-and.html) for that.

Comment: Hmmm, where do we require that to? In the webpack config? Index.js, or styles.css?

Comment: In fact you can just import bootstrap like this 

`import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Comment: Which file should we put `require('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css');`?